# Not being able to re-create an ODBC for MsSQL server conection on Excel for MAC

Tags: excel, vba, macos, odbc

I am wirting an excel file to be comaptible with mac, and I do not have a mac with me, so I connect to a mac friend to record a macro and emulate: I got this code creating a simple call to my server:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=myserver.database.windows.net;Database=mydb;UID=myuser;" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandText = Array("select * from mytable")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .RefreshPeriod = False
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("C2").Select
End Sub
```

got it to windows, test, it , everything ok,

so I wrote the following code, basically 100% the same, with a new query:

```
Sub demo__myCall()
  
  Dim sqlstring As String
  Dim sLogin As String
  Dim connstring As String
  Dim destinationCells As Range
    
  Set destinationCells = Sheets("mySheet").Range("A10")

    
  sLogin = "UID=myuser;Pwd=mypawd&123;"
               
  connstring = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=myserver.database.windows.net;Database=mydb;" & sLogin
  
  Dim lo As ListObject
    For Each lo In Sheets("mySheet").ListObjects
        lo.Delete
    Next lo

  
    
    sqlstring = "select * from myothertable"
                
     
     With Sheets("INTERNAL").ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=connstring, Destination:=destinationCells).QueryTable
        .CommandText = Array(sqlstring)
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells 'xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = True
        .SaveData = True
        .RefreshPeriod = False
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
     End With
   
 
End Sub
```

as you can see, difernec are minimun,

get back to mac, test the original one (Macro1), works ok, test the second one (demo__myCall) got the error "can not complete operation becouse ODBC controler is not installed" (or something like this as original message is in spanish)

back to MAcro 1, works, back to demo_myCall, does NOT work ...

can anybody help me?

Comment: Isn't the error clear? You need the required MSSQL ODBC driver installed with `SQL Server` alias. Your Mac friend has such a driver but you do not on Windows. Open PowerShell and check: `Get-OdbcDriver -name SQL*`. If blank, install accordingly: [Download ODBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Hi @Parfait, thanks for response, how comes with the first code no need of any SQL driver, and with the second there is a need ?   Thants mainly my concern

Comment: Your code won't run on your friends Mac even though the connection string is the same as the macro he recorded. Is that the problem ?

Comment: exactly, thts the problem,

Comment: indeed I add both pieces of code in the same sub, one works, the second fail

Comment: This is an educated guess - try adding curly brackets around driver   like DRIVER={SQL Server}